# Task manager for Android and Profiler for SmartWatches (AndroidWear)

Tags: android, performance, wear-os, taskmanager, sony-smartwatch

Is there any app or way like task manager where I can close individual apps on a smartwatch (Android wear) ? Also if there is any way to measure cpu, memory, and battery consumption of individual apps on Android wear ?

For task manager, I have already tried [Task Manager for Android wear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rocketstartups.weartaskmanager&hl=en) But it doesn't work on my LG Watch R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may be more suited in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) instead of stackoverflow.

Anyways, if you're looking for an app, you can try this [Task Manager For Android Wear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rocketstartups.weartaskmanager&hl=en) that is available in the Play Store. It can list all running processes on your watch and it can help you to stop any of the tasks easily and quickly.

You can also check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/performance.html) for tips for conserving power and improving performance. You need to ensure that your watch face performs computations only when active; use callbacks in [`WatchFaceService.Engine`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceService.Engine.html). The [Android Wear companion app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app&hl=en) also enables developers and users to see how much battery is consumed by different processes on the wearable device (under Settings > Watch battery).

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried Task manager for Android wear but it didn't work. I updated it in my question.

Comment: For the battery statistics, I can see them from that option. thanks